# Salesforce lightning performance component

Tags: lightning, performance, home-page-component

I'm trying to configure the new homepage since my org just recently switched to lightning. I added the performance component to the layout, however it doesn't show any data. It just says "to see your opportunity related data, contact your salesforce admin." The only issue is, I am the admin! How do I get this component to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for the [performance chart](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.home_performance_chart_lex.htm&type=5) states that:

> The performance chart isn’t compatible with custom fiscal years. If
> your org has custom fiscal years enabled, your admin can create custom
> reports and dashboards to display on the Home page.

That is a likely reason.

Althernatively it may be the case that you don't have read access to the opportunity object or the relevant fields.